# Twitter Sign in Quickblox

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, token, quickblox

Hi so I have been working on this project for months now and my client just turned around and asked could you add a twitter login button.

I said sure because I know that Quickblox can do that sort of thing.

Only trouble is I can't get this to work on android.

I have followed the documentation and looked at the sample. http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization

The sample does not show how to authenticate the user in the app, only a code snippet.
I dont know how to integrate this. Could someone please help??

I have worked with twitter before just not with quickblox. I have my keys and access tokens I just need to know how do I get access tokens for my users and how do I use quickblox to integrate it??

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect Twitter library like twitter4j or other

Next it should be steps like:

1. login via twitter4j or other lib
2. get twitter access token
3. use this token to login to quickblox